# Subselecting array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have the following tables:

> chatUsers

```
chatId   | userId        |
---------|---------------|
1        | 1             |
1        | 2             |
2        | 1             |
2        | 3             |
```

> chatRooms

```
chatId   |lastMessageTime|
---------|---------------|
1        | yesterday     | //for example 1000000000
2        | today         | //for example 1532473344
```

Let's say I am `userId 1`

I would like to load all the chatRooms that I am in.

Ordered by `chatRooms.lastMessageTime` + I'd like to know what users are in the same chat room (`chatUsers.userId`)

So for example in this case:

```
 [{
   "chatId": 2,
   "users": [1, 3]
 },
 {
   "chatId": 1,
   "users": [1, 2]
 }]
```

Is it possible? I've managed to make it without the users selection:

```
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT cr.chatId FROM chatRooms AS cr INNER JOIN chatUsers AS cu ON cu.chatId = cr.chatId WHERE cu.userId = :userId 
  ORDER BY cr.lastMessageTime DESC, cr.chatId DESC');
$qry->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry->execute();

$chatRooms = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But I am unable to make a subselect inside the select..

Comment: No nested results in MySQL, or any SQL that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT cr.chatId, GROUP_CONCAT(cu.userId) AS users FROM chatRooms AS cr INNER JOIN chatUsers AS cu ON cu.chatId = cr.chatId WHERE cu.userId = :userId ORDER BY cr.lastMessageTime DESC, cr.chatId DESC GROUP BY chatId');
$qry->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry->execute();

$chatRooms = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In this way you'll get users in a comma-separated string.